# Warning message while running nodejs file

Tags: node.js, express

I am beginner in node js, i worte a code to get the form data from html using express and it allways shows the warning.
"body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option app.js:11:17"

here is my code

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app=express()

const port=process.env.PORT || 3000

const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '')

app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.json())


app.get('',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index')
}) 

app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.body)
        res.send('thankyou for submission')
    }catch(error){
        res.send()
    }
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('server started to'+port);
  })
```

Comment: This is not a javascript question, but solely a node.js question (maybe express too is relevant)

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace

```
app.use(express.urlencoded())
```

with

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and dont forget to require bodyparser

```
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the option "extended" when using the bodyParser since the default value is going to change. Use this on line 11:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Also include the bodyParser module with:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```